# Why I cannot get the difference in time between two clicks in android?

Tags: android

I want to calculate in seconds the difference in time between two cliks so

I use

```
   public void onClick(View view) {
   Long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();

   switch(x)
   case button1:
   Long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   break;
   case button2:
   Long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   break;
 }

 Long differenz = (endtime-starttime)/1000;
```

but I get 0

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long is an integer, so the system is trying to automatically cast a precision number to the nearest integer.
You should use a double or float for the result, try changing line

Long differenz = (endtime-starttime)/1000;

to:

double differenz = (double)((endtime-starttime)/1000);

Answer (score 0):

Long starttime,endtime ; (outer most scope recommended)

Create this variable outside of the scope of onClickListener because each button will have a separate copy of the instance of so you will cannot have a common data shared between the like this

```
public void onClick(View view) {

if(starttime == null) 
starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();

endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Long differenz = (endtime-starttime)/1000;